# Color picker implementation

Tags: extjs4

```js
Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Picker', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    id: 'colorpicker',

    createPicker: function() {
        return Ext.create('Ext.picker.Color', {
            resizable: true,
            floating: true,

            select: function(selColor) {
                Ext.getCmp('colorpicker').setValue("#" + selColor);
                var x = Ext.getCmp('colorpicker').getValue();
                alert(x);
                Ext.getCmp('colorpicker').setFieldStyle('background-color:x ;background-image: none;');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

In above sample of code I created a color picker by implementing create picker method of `EXt.form.field.Picker` as per [ExtJS 4.0.7 sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Picker).

### First Question

I am able to get the output only when I specify floating config to true (as mentioned in above sample). If I remove the config or made it false I am not able to see the color picker in the output so what is the reason behind that can anyone explain why floating config should be true?

### Second Question

By using above sample code, I am getting the output but the color picker rendering has some problem one time it will display correctly while clicking on picker field drop down but sometimes color picker will appear above the field or somewhere on the page when drop down is clicked. So how to avoid this? I want to show it below when picker drop down is clicked.

### Third Question

I want to apply background of the picker filed with the selected color value so I added the following line of code:

```
Ext.getCmp('colorpicker')
   .setFieldStyle('background-color:x ;background-image: none;');`
```

Where `x` is the selected color value (say `#000000` is color value when we select black color from color picker) but it is not applying color to text filed

When I replace `x` value with `#000000` in that line of code say:

```
Ext.getCmp('colorpicker')
    .setFieldStyle('background-color:#000000 ;background-image: none;');
```

Then it is showing black color for filed background but i want the color to be changed to selected color so I can't give the static color value.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second question:
Instead of passing the string 'x' to the function ...

```
Ext.getCmp('colorpicker').setFieldStyle('background-color:x ;background-image: none;');
```

you should try something like:

```
Ext.getCmp('colorpicker').setFieldStyle('background-color:' + x + ' ;background-image: none;');
```